# Laravel query with relationship where have all ids

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I try to do a query where I get a **room** where I have all the **services**.

With my current code I get the **room** that has at least one of the **services** from the array, because I am using `whereIn`.

```
$rooms = Room::select([
    'rooms.id',
    'rooms.available_from',
    'rooms.available_till',
    'rooms.description',
    'rooms.room_type_id',
    'room_types.name as room_types_name',
])
    ->leftJoin('room_types', 'room_types.id', 'rooms.room_type_id')
    ->with('services','reserved_rooms')
    ->when($request->services, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereHas('services', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->whereIn('id', $request->services);
        });
    })
    ->orderByDesc('id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: What is the exact question ?

Comment: I am looking for an alternative to my query. Now I get rooms where I have at least 1 service (conditions is OR), but I need to be AND. Ex. If am I searching for a room with TV and POOL, I should get a room with both services, not just 1 of them.

Comment: I think you should take a different approach to the query, can you add the table + columns to your question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match all services, you can use `for` `loop` to create AND query.

Try below code:

```
->when($request->services, function ($query) use ($request) {
    foreach ($request->services as $key => $service) {
        $query->whereHas('services', function ($q) use ($service) {
            $q->where('id', $service);
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Works fine when service is NULL or I have selected just 1 service, but when I selected more, the query is empty.

Comment: when you select multiple, what will be your value in $request->services, it is array or comma saperated value

Comment: It's an array. I also have use it on whereIn .

Comment: have you did this:            $q->where('id', $value);

Comment: Yes, I did it, but works just for NULL or 1 service.

Comment: Can you put  ->toSql() to check  query

Comment: "select `rooms`.`id`, `rooms`.`available_from`, `rooms`.`available_till`, `rooms`.`description`, `rooms`.`room_type_id`, `room_types`.`name` as `room_types_name` from `rooms` left join `room_types` on `room_types`.`id` = `rooms`.`room_type_id` where exists (select * from `services` inner join `room_service` on `services`.`id` = `room_service`.`service_id` where `rooms`.`id` = `room_service`.`room_id` and `id` = ?) order by `id` desc"

Comment: Pass multiple values in $request->services and check in for loop

Comment: I have multiple services on dd, and I get multiple values in array

Comment: So it is coming in for each  loop?

Comment: Try using orWhere:             $q->orWhere('id', $value);

Comment: If you edit the answer and do the forEach outside whereHas this solution works. Please edit it to accept your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
->when($request->services, function ($query) use ($request) {
        $query->whereHas('services', function ($q) use ($request) {
            $q->selectRaw('count(distinct id)')->whereIn('id', $request->services);
        }, '=', count($request->services)
);
    })
```

Changed it,not tested but this is the general idea: get the rows where the COUNT of distinct ids is equal to the length of array.The array should be unique.

Comment: It seems like the same thing, but in this case I get an error: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (

Comment: @Beusebiu Just specify the table name, 'services.id' or whatever table name you need.

Comment: I tried, I also tried to include it in the select, but still the same.

Comment: @Beusebiu Changed it.

Comment: I tried this and now I get: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 4078 Illegal parameter data types row and int for operation '=' (SQL: select `rooms`.`id`, ... but from this logic I don't think is ok, because with this logic I will get only the rooms where I have TV and POOL, but my need is to contain those to, NOT to have only those two.